# Page not loading after PHP include added on top line

Tags: php

Im creating a sign up and login page, however it was working untill i added a php include line at the top, now the page just loads showing the actual raw code and not the log in page, can anyone tell me where i am going wrong please?

```
<?php include('functions.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
            <title>Registration system PHP and MySQL</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
           <h2>Register</h2>
</div>
<form method="post" action="register.php">
<?php echo display_error(); ?>
      <div class="input-group">
         <label>Username</label>
         <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
         <label>Email</label>
         <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
         <label>Password</label>
         <input type="password" name="password_1">
      </div>
         <div class="input-group">
         <label>Confirm password</label>
         <input type="password" name="password_2">
      </div>
         <div class="input-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="register_btn">Register</button>
      </div>
      <p>
              Already a member? <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
      </p>
      </form>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: You need to show us `functions.php`. The problem likely lies in that script.

Comment: Is the file you included it in also `.php`?

Comment: Is `functions.php` on the same `dir`?

Comment: yeah they are all in the same folder which i made and saved in htdocs

Comment: and yes the file is in .php

Comment: Enable php `display_errors` in order to properly debug your code. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);.`  right after `<?php` and re-run your script, does it output any errors?

Comment: i have just added the display error code after the php and i have also enabled the display_errors its still just showing me the raw code

Comment: its in htdocs but is local server actually running?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Answer (score 0):

you're not running your code from server,put your projects in this directory 
if you're using  in :

**Xampp :**  `C:\xampp\htdocs`

or

**Wamp:**  `C:\wamp\www`